# srand(time(null)) on iPhone don't work =(

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random, srand

I need generate random numbers in my iPhone game.
I using rand() function.
But it isn't enough random.
I tried using srand with time(Null).
But my random generator was periodic.
/dev/random isn't an answer because I need new random number each 0.1 sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS and OS X, use [arc4random](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) instead. Higher quality randomness, and no need to worry about seeding.

However, `rand()` shouldn't be noticably periodic, unless you're calling `srand` each time around. Or using the random numbers incorrectly.

Comment: arc4random() uses /dev/random as source.

Comment: Yes. I call srand() everytime. =( I thought it would solve my problem with rand().

Comment: @JustSid: arc4random uses `/dev/urandom` (not `/dev/random`) for the *seed*, and when you manually call `arc4random_stir`.

Comment: @Riddick: `srand()` should only be called once; think for example what happens if you call `srand(time(NULL))` twice or more within the same second. And in general calling it with `time(NULL)` is not the greatest idea either (it's too predictable), although for a game it probably doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 3):

You could try random() / srandom() instead. Better generator than rand() / srand().

Answer (score 0):

Are you building for debug or on the simulator?  I know I ran into this kind of issue when building some windows applications in debug, the RNG was automatically seeded with a constant value to produce consistent results.  You may want to check what it is actually seeded with, and if you are getting different outputs at all each run.